# Как определить к какому TCP пакету относится недополученная часть?

Tags: c++, сокет, tcp

Есть система потоковой аудио-видео трансляции. Клиент подключается к серверу по одному TCP сокету, через который раздельно передаёт кодированные кадры камеры, экрана и звуковые семплы, блокируя сокет критической секцией при каждой отправке, чтобы пакеты не путались. Пакеты предварительно кодируются по протоколу WebSocket - во-первых для унификации взаимодействия сервера как со стримером на C++, так и с браузером наблюдателя, а во вторых по стандарту WebSocket можно из заголовка понять размер пакета, который планировал передать клиент и "дочитать" его если он пришёл не полный. Сервер использует технологию IOCP.

Проблема заключается в том, что если пакет пришёл не полный (длина указанная в заголовке WebSocket-а больше чем принято байт), инициируется новый overlapped `WSARecv`... только вот как показала практика, не факт, что следующим будет вычитан именно оставшийся кусок пакета, а не новый фрейм от другого медиа-источника на этом же сокете. В результате на клиенте то пакеты не путаются, а вот сервер их путает если какое-то сообщение хоть раз вычитал не полностью.

Конечно разделение стрима на три сокета решит проблему, но всё же хотелось бы выяснить можно ли как-то определить, что недочитанная часть относится к конкретному TCP пакету?

Comment: Вы случаем с UDP не перепутали?

Comment: @VTT, нет. WebSocket по UDP не ходит. Во всяком случае не реализовано в браузерах

Comment: Я про разделение по пакетам.

Comment: @Abyx, бывает WSARecv вычитывает не всё, и приходится вызывать повторно. В данном случае почему-то вычитывает не недочитанный пакет, а новый, поскольку IOCP работает в несколько потоков, а событие приёма одно на подключение